# Implementation of saving settings

Tags: java, android, serialization, save

I am writing kind of game on android. And i wonder how to save settings in order not to have problems with updates.
For example I save settings with serialization, I have class `GameChar`

```
public class GameChar implements Serializable{

  int health;
  int damage;

  Sword sword;
}
```

But later i decide to add value armor to my game character, i change class:

```
public class GameChar implements Serializable{

  int health;
  int damage;

  int armor;

  Sword sword;
}
```

And now with update i loose all progress because new class `GameChar` is not the same as `GameChar`.
I have an idea to use `Map<String, Object>` where key is name of value i save and value is any `Object` i want(`Integer`, `Float`, `Calendar` or some my user class `Sword`). And i will save this `Map` to file with `Serialization`.

But if i change some of my user class `Sword` it will be not the same as already in my `Map` and once again i will loose progress with update.

Maybe there is some pattern or technic that i miss to make it more elegant.

Comment: How about if you use a DB like Sqlite file based/local database. And simply save just the variables. Then when you have an update you can add any number of new variables and simply read old variable values back.  
This is how i solved my problem which was pretty similar to that. I didn't notice a big change in performance so it was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice that, when implementing `Serializable`, you are asked to declare a `static long` called `serialVersionUID`?

The purpose of this variable is to detect older versions of the Class when deserializing. Attempting to deserialize a version `1` object from saved data using a version `2` class will result in an exception.

(You can implement this behavior yourself, if you don't use Java's serialization facilities, it's just a number and an `if`)

Once you detect that the object you saved is stale, and doesn't match the current class definition, you can manually fix the issue. For example, if you know that a new member `int a;` is declared in version `2`, and you pick up an object serialized with version `1`, you can assign a value that makes sense despite being missing in the saved information.

Keeping track of versions is your job, unfortunately. The easiest way around this is to ensure that a newer version can always be instantiated from an older version with no adjustments -- for example, having `null` be a meaningful value.

Comment: This is correct and good advice from downside up, as it pertains to regular Java serialization. Still, I'd recommend avoiding standard Java serialization for what you need on Android (way too much overhead and complexity for what you need). As others have noted, use SharedPreferences (which is to say, use the file system with properties), or use a DB. Or, one of my favorites, use Gson and just serialize json strings to files. This is super easy and puts all the hard work off onto Gson.

Comment: So I should manually set serialVersionUID. And in process of deserializtion of older version of file it still would be read but missing field will be set to default value and knowing serialVersionUID i should set corresponding value to it? (because now when i do not set serialVersionUID manually and add some field to class i just cant retrieve it from file - I get exception)

Comment: As Charlie said, Java native serialization is best when avoided. I would just use plain static integers for versions and an `if` on a custom deserialization method (no exceptions thrown). You can [check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) if you do want to use Java's tool

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you should take a look into the SharedPreferences (which is a kind of a map)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

from your example class I would use it and not serialise the class at all, just manually save each individual item into the SharedPreferences and never have any serialisation issues.

Comment: As I understand in SharedPreferences as a value I can store only primitives - which is not good for me because i should store not only primitives but also my user classes and even Collections of them.

Comment: Using `implements Serializable` you'll always have the upgrade issue. So no matter what is the actual approach you'll take it is advisable to store the primitives and build the objects based on them. My answer was based on the fact that you show some fairly simple object in the question, but if you need more robust ways of storing the data, the way to go is with a database (SQLite)

Answer (score 0):

Essentialy you are going to check the version of the object as you deserialize it and replace it with an updated version. [Check this link out](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/)

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is to overwrite the readObject Method and catch the EOFException that occures if you read in a serialized previous version of GameChar. In the exeption handler you can assign a default value to armor then. Since this requires to declare the variables transient you also need to overwrite the writeObject method. This example does not contain Sword, which itself should overwrite the readObject and writeObject methods if there are different versions of Sword (same procedure). In case of more than 2 versions one should use a variable "version" and read objects according to the value of that variable.

```
public class GameChar implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L; // use serialver to determine UID
transient private int health;
transient private int damage;
transient private int armor;

private synchronized void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
        throws IOException {
    s.writeInt(health);
    s.writeInt(damage);
    s.writeInt(armor);

}

private synchronized void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    health = s.readInt();
    damage = s.readInt();
    try {
        armor = s.readInt();
    } catch (EOFException eofex) {
        armor = 999; // default value
    }
}
}
```

If you use such "version" variable the readObject method may look like this:

```
private synchronized void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
        throws IOException {
    version = s.readInt();
    health = s.readInt();
    damage = s.readInt();
    switch(version) {
        case 1: armor = 999; // default;
            break;
        case 2: armor = s.readInt();
    }
}
```